# Schema is not a constructor - Mongoose/Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This question has definitely been answered many times, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I'm a beginner on Mongoose/Node and am following a PluralSight tutorial where I am getting the error in the title. It's specifically pointing to line 4 of bookModel.js. I have included both of my JavaScript files below as well as my package.json in case there's something about my package versions.

As far as I can tell, my code is identical to the tutorial and is very similar to virtually every solution I could find, but I'm still receiving the same error.

I apologize for the dumb question, but I've been struggling with this for a while and am dead in the water.

Thanks

**models/bookModel.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
Schema = mongoose.Schema();

var bookModel = new Schema({
  title: {type: String},
  author: {type: String},
  genre: {type: String},
  read: {type: Boolean, default:false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Book", bookModel);
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express")
mongoose = require("mongoose");

var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/bookAPI");

var Book = require("./models/bookModel");

var app = express();
var port = process.env.port || 3000;

var bookRouter = express.Router();
bookRouter.route("/books")
  .get(function(req, res){
      Book.find(function(err, books){
          if(err){
              res.status(500).send(err);
          }
          else{
              res.json(books);
          }
      })


  });

app.use("/api", bookRouter);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "bookapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.2.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.7"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
Schema = mongoose.Schema();
```

It's not a constructor indeed because `Schema` is the result of `mongoose.Schema()` call, i.e. dummy schema object.

It should be:

```
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I went back and watched the video again and it appears there's a typo in the course. I'll make sure to let the author know!

Comment: Glad it was that simple. Yes, a typo like this one defies the purpose of a tutorial a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the schema this way.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),

var bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: {type: String},
   author: {type: String},
   genre: {type: String},
   read: {type: Boolean, default:false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Book", bookSchema);
```